# Compile VLC for android Failed

Tags: android, vlc

Dears,

Recently, I am confused with how to compile vlc for android successful.
I try to https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/#Android_Studio.2C_SDK_and_NDK_installation
on my Ubuntu 14.04, but failed. I get the tips like:

```
callon@ubuntu:/opt/vlc_src/vlc-android$ sh compile.sh 
*** No ANDROID_ABI defined architecture: using ARMv7

VLC source found
Configuring
ABI:        armeabi-v7a
API:        9

PATH:       /opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/toolchains/arm/bin:/opt/AndroidSDK/platform-tools:/opt/android-ndk-r11c:/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/eclipse:/opt/AndroidSDK/platforms:/opt/AndroidSDK/tools:/opt/android-studio/bin:/opt/genymobile/genymotion:/opt/AndroidSDK/platform-tools:/opt/AndroidSDK/tools
EXTRA_CFLAGS:      -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -MMD -MP -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-integrated-as
VLC_CFLAGS:        -std=gnu11 -g -O2 -fstrict-aliasing -funsafe-math-optimizations
Building tools
protoc too old
To-be-built packages: protoc
You are ready to build VLC and its contribs
make: `.gas' is up to date.
Building the contribs
Generating EGL pkg-config file
Generating GLESv2 pkg-config file
Guessing build system... x86_64-linux-gnu
Creating configuration file... config.mak
Bootstrap completed.
Run "make" to start compilation.

Other targets:
 * make install      same as "make"
 * make prebuilt     fetch and install prebuilt binaries
 * make list         list packages
 * make fetch        fetch required source tarballs
 * make fetch-all    fetch all source tarballs
 * make distclean    clean everything and undo bootstrap
 * make mostlyclean  clean everything except source tarballs
 * make clean        clean everything
 * make package      prepare prebuilt packages
 * make help         show this text
make: Nothing to be done for `fetch'.
mkdir -p -- /opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal && cd a52dec && autoreconf -fiv -I/opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal
mkdir -p -- /opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal && cd openjpeg && autoreconf -fiv -I/opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.in: not using Gettext
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I /opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal --force 
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I /opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal --force -I m4
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
autoreconf: configure.in: tracing
autoreconf: configure.in: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin/autoconf --include=/opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal --force
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
configure.in:74: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_SHARED
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.in:75: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL
configure.in:76: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
autoreconf: /opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
make: *** [.a52] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin/autoconf --include=/opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal --force
autoreconf: running: /opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin/autoheader --include=/opt/vlc_src/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
applications/jpip/libopenjpip/Makefile.am:6: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
applications/jpip/libopenjpip/Makefile.am:6:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
applications/jpip/libopenjpip/Makefile.am:6:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
applications/jpip/libopenjpip/Makefile.am:6:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
applications/jpip/libopenjpip/Makefile.am:6:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
libopenjpeg/Makefile.am:12: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
libopenjpeg/Makefile.am:12:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
libopenjpeg/Makefile.am:12:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
libopenjpeg/Makefile.am:12:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
libopenjpeg/Makefile.am:12:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
libopenjpeg/jpwl/Makefile.am:3: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
libopenjpeg/jpwl/Makefile.am:3:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
libopenjpeg/jpwl/Makefile.am:3:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
libopenjpeg/jpwl/Makefile.am:3:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
libopenjpeg/jpwl/Makefile.am:3:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
make: *** [.openjpeg] Error 1
contribs: make failed
callon@ubuntu:/opt/vlc_src/vlc-android$
```

I follow https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=108927 to fix it, but failed again, it seems I don't use libtool, but I already install it and I try to use LT_INIT in some configure.in and configure.ac. No way can fix it.

Comment: i use ubuntu 16.04 64-bit to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution? This github issue comment recommends using libtoolize: https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk/issues/45#issuecomment-247840053